# A list of techniques to find optimal point of an optimization problem algorithmically?

Tags: convex-optimization

I am interested to collect and analyze a list of technique to find an optimal point of an optimization problem algorithmically as follows:

Problem: Find a point where the gradient has non-negative inner product  with any feasible direction at the point.

Methods:

1. Gradient descent: It is best suited to unconstrained convex problem, more specifically unconstrained strongly convex problem. It is very sensitive to condition number of the Hessian at the current iterate and change of co-ordinates.
2. Newton method: It is best suited to unconstrained convex problem and equality constrained convex problem, more specifically unconstrained self-concordance problem.
3. Interior point method (barrier method and central path): It is best suited to inequality constrained convex problem.
4. Primal-dual interior point method: Closely related to barrier method but not quite the same as it needs to introduce surrogate duality gap for stopping criteria. It is best suited to semi-definite program.

Can we do futher analysis and discussion of these techniques in order to summarize the process of finding optimal points algorithmically.?

Answer (score 1):

### List of optimization techniques

(i) Least squares computed exactly

**Unconstrained optimization**:

(ii) Conjugate gradient least squares

(iii) Gradient descent

(iv) Momentum gradient descent

(v) Newton's method

(vi) BFGS

(vii) Proximal gradient method, Majorization minimization (non-smooth)

(viii) ISTA, FISTA (non-smooth)

**Constrained optimization**:

(ix) ADMM

(x) Dual ascent

### Examples

(1) $\min_x \|y-Ax\|^2$ with $x$ having $100,000$ variables, $y$ consisting of $200,000$ observations and $A$ is sparse.

**Conjugate gradient** should be used as $A^*$ can easily be computed due to $A$'s sparsity.

(2) Minimize a function $f(x_1, x_2)$. The function consists of only exponents and polynomials in $x_1, x_2$. The exact solution should be reached in a small number of steps.

**Newton's method** should be used as since the function consists of only polynomials and exponents, the gradient and hessian can be analytically computed.

(3) Minimize a smooth function $f(x)$ with $x$ having $10,000$ variables.

**Momentum gradient descent** should be used. Newton's method cannot be used as solving a 10000 x 10000 inverse problem on each iteration is infeasible. Momentum gradient descent has a better convergence rate for ill-conditioned problems than gradient descent.

(4) Minimize a function $f(x)$ with $100$ variables, where the eigenvalues of the hessian range from $10^{-3}$ to $10^6$.

**Momentum gradient descent** or **Newton's method** should be used. With 100 variables, Newton's method is reasonable and improves upon poor conditioning. Momentum gradient descent is also acceptable since it improves upon gradient descent for ill-conditioning.

(5) Minimize $f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is smooth with an ill-conditioned Hessian, but a small number of variables.

*Newton's method* can overcome an ill-conditioned problem with a small number of variables

(6) Minimize $f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is smooth with an ill-conditioned Hessian and a large number of variables.

*Momentum gradient descent* does better than gradient descent, though not as well as Newton's method, for ill-conditioned problems when the computational complexity becomes too high for a large number of variables.

(7) Minimize $\| Y-A(X) \|^2_F + \lambda \|X\|_F^2$ where $X$ is a matrix representing a large image and $A(X)$ is a linear blurring operator. Each pixel output of $A(X)$ depends only on a small number of pixels of $X$.

(8) Minimize $\|y-x\|_2^2+\lambda \|Ax\|_1$ where $A$ is some matrix.

(9) Minimize $\sum_{i=1}^K f_i(x_i)$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^K c_i^Tx_i=0$ for some functions $f_i(x_i)$ and vectors $c_i$.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting list of techniques, may you add an summarized algorithm to each algorithm for a better application and visualization perspective.